# Group table ID and only show one records without certain string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table with following data:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 933 | Jack - Dit |
| 566 | Mary |
| 566 | Mary - code |
| 566 | Mary - Sit |
| 933 | Jack - Dit |
| 933 | Jack - Dit |
| 933 | Jack |
| 144 | Bod |

I need to use `Group by` to group the `ID` and only show 1 record without `'-'` :

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 933 | Jack |
| 566 | Mary |
| 144 | Bod |

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I use SQL Server, I have changed my tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you actually need to use `GROUP BY`. Based on the data shown, a simple `SELECT DISTINCT` should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, [Name]
FROM tblData
WHERE InStr([Name],"-")=0;
```